# Mapping schema data base with Data Base in R2DBC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, postgresql-9.1, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm starting with a Spring Boot + WebFlux + Postgresql project.

It is necessary to carry out the mapping of the bank schema, but in the @Table annotation the schema information is not present, thinking about it I wanted to understand how it would be possible to carry out the mapping for a table contained in a schema.

Table

```
select id, description from myschema.mytable;
```

Mapping

```
package br.com.myschema.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table
public class MyTableEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String description;
}
```

How would it be possible to define for the spring-data that I am accessing the owner myschema?

Comment: Most probably unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a initial script using [ConnectionFactoryInitializer](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/data-r2dbc-repositories/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DatabaseConfig.java#L62)  to select the schema to use.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS tenant1 ; 
SHOW search_path;
SET search_path  TO tenant1;
```